# move forward turtlebot2 in the real world

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys. I want to move the turtlebot. I am using Hydro and KobukiBase. Firstly i created package inside my catkin_ws:

```
$ catkin_create_pkg forward std_msgs rospy roscpp actionlib tf geometry_msgs move_base_msgs .
```

Then i edit CMakeList:

```
add_executable(gg src/gg.cpp) and target_link_libraries(gg, ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

Thirdly, i run these commads:

```
catkin_make
roscore
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:'pwd'
source ./devel/setup.bash
rosrun forward gg.cpp
```

gg.cpp :

```
 #include <ros/ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <tf/transform_datatypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <tf/transform_listener.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <geometry_msgs/PointStamped.h>
#include <std_msgs/Header.h>
#include <iostream>


int main(){

 geometry_msgs::PointStamped p;
 geometry_msgs::PointStamped p1;
 p.header.stamp = ros::Time();
 std::string frame1 = "/camera_depth_optical_frame";
 p.header.frame_id = frame1.c_str();

 p.point.x = 0;
 p.point.y = 0;
 p.point.z = 1; // 1 meter

// std::string frame = "map";

 /*try
 {
   listener.transformPoint(frame,p,p1);
 }catch(tf::TransformException& ex) { ROS_ERROR("exception while transforming..."); }
*/
 // create message for move_base_simple/goal 
 geometry_msgs::PoseStamped msg;
 msg.header.stamp = ros::Time();
 std::string frame = "/map";
 msg.header.frame_id = frame.c_str();
 msg.pose.position = p1.point;
 msg.pose.orientation = tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw(0.0);
 //publisher.publish(msg);

}
```

errors:

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named gg.cpp below /home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/src/forward
[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files,
[rosrun] or not executable:
[rosrun]   /home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/src/forward/src/gg.cpp
```

I think this code is correct and executable but rosrun command is wrong. I don't fix this. What do you think about these errors?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196671/move-forward-turtlebot2-in-the-real-world/) by [ros_master](https://answers.ros.org/users/20662/ros_master/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-11-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you try to compile your node before ros knows about your workspace.

so

1. "source ./devel/setup.bash" or even better, source the setup.bash in your .bashrc
2. do catkin_make in your workspace
3. if you got no errors, rosrun your node with

   rosrun forward gg

**IMPORTANT:** you CANT rosrun a cpp file and never change ROS_PACKAGE_PATH by hand! always source the setup.bash

---

Originally posted by [lebowski](https://answers.ros.org/users/20622/lebowski/) with karma: 146 on 2014-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0